# Firebase Auth `getRedirectResult` is always null when I run the app in Safari

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I am developing a web app using Firebase.
I have a question because the Firebase Auth `getRedirectResult` is always null when I run the app in Safari.

The front end is using Next.js.

The correct behavior of the app is as follows

1. when you click the "Sign in with Google" button from the login page, you will be redirected to `/auth-redirect?redirect_uri=onboarding`
2. `getRedirectResult` will be null and use `signInWithRedirect` to authenticate
3. Authentication provider calls back to `/auth-redirect?redirect_uri=onboarding` via Firebase.
4. `getRedirectResult` becomes non-null and moves to redirect_uri

I expect the above behavior, but when using Safari, the result of `getRedirectResult` is still `null` at 4. When using chrome, it is non-null.

The `auth-redirect` is implemented as follows.

```
import { NextPage } from 'next'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import * as firebaseAuth from 'firebase/auth'
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import { auth } from '../lib/firebase'

const redirectableWhiteList = ['', 'onboarding']

const AuthRedirectPage: NextPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!router.isReady) {
      return
    }

    ;(async () => {
      const result = await firebaseAuth.getRedirectResult(auth)
      if (result == null) {
        await firebaseAuth
          .signInWithRedirect(auth, new firebaseAuth.GoogleAuthProvider())
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
          })

      } else {
        const redirectUri = router.query['redirect_uri'] as string | undefined
        if (redirectableWhiteList.includes(redirectUri)) {
          router.push(redirectUri)
        } else {
          router.push(redirectUri || '/')
        }
      }
    })()
  }, [router, router.isReady])

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className='text-center'>
        <div className='row justify-content-center'>
          <h1>Loading</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default AuthRedirectPage
```

Why is `const result = await firebaseAuth.getRedirectResult(auth)` null when using Safari?

When I look at the log in the web inspector, I see that only when using Safari
`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/_next/webpack-hmr' failed: WebSocket is closed due to suspension.` error, but since it is HMR, I don't think there is a problem.

I would appreciate your advice as I have no idea what to consider.

my environment

- Safari version: 16.2 (18614.3.7.1.5)
- Chrome version: 109.0.5414.87（Official Build） （arm64）
- next version: 13.0.6
- firebase vesion: 9.8.1

Comment: I am having the same issue. On firefox it's even worse: it will randomly complain about a missing state after you log in. I'm also using sign in with google, but I'm on SvelteKit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am deploying to vercel.
I have confirmed that this method works fine.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6716#issuecomment-1331981547

- Reverse proxy settings(next.config.js)

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,

  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/__/auth/:path*',
        destination: `https://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN}/__/auth/:path*`,
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

- Changed authDomain when initializing FirebaseApp to the app's domain
- In GCP, change approved redirect URI to `https://<the-domain-that-serves-my-app>/__/auth/handler`.